# CAML Query Failed After Implementing OR

Tags: sharepoint, caml

In my SharePoint `CAML` query, when filtering with one input, it is successful. However, when I add in `<Or>` to include one more input, it failed.

Below are the `CAML` queries. Is the error due to wrong formatting of Multiple Input?

---

**Single input (pass)**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
        </Eq>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">"Document"</Value></Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

---

**Multiple input (fail)**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <Or>
                <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
            </Or>
        </Eq>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">"Document"</Value></Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

---

*Error:*

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()

Comment: or is parent element not child element . Please use any caml builder like Stramit, U2U caml  or etc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/or-element-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Problems with your CAML query. It should be like

```
<Where>
    <And>
           <Or>
               <Eq> <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value> </Eq>
               <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value> </Eq>
            </Or>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">"Document"</Value></Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```